# Long press gesture on image in tableview custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I need some help. Today, I am working on table view custom cell where the cell contains an `UIImageView`. On the ImageView, I want to implement the long gesture. I implement code for this that is give below.. But I am doing something wrong in my code.In this the View is resize once on long press but i want after the some seconds it can be remove and come back in table view cell 
  Can anyone Suggest me????

Update:

[image: long gesture Image]

Here's the code!

```
- (void)celllongpressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{

if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    cell = (ActivityFeedCell *)[gesture view];
}
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    cell = (ActivityFeedCell *)[gesture view];
    logGes_view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0,self.view.frame.size.width-10,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    image=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-80)];
    image.image=cell.updated_imgView.image;
    UILabel *name_label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 15, 150, 30)];
    //city_label.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
    name_label.text=lgGesNamelbl;
    UILabel *city_label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 180, 30)];
    //city_label.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
    city_label.text=lgGesCitylbl;
    [logGes_view addSubview:city_label];
      [logGes_view addSubview:name_label];
    [logGes_view addSubview:image];
    logGes_view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:logGes_view];
}
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
   // cell = (ActivityFeedCell *)[gesture view];
    [logGes_view removeFromSuperview];
}
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture1 = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(celllongpressed:)];
[gesture1 setDelegate:self];
[gesture1 setMinimumPressDuration:1.0];
[ cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell addGestureRecognizer:gesture1];
}
```

Comment: Show the resulting output and code which you have write for the same.

Comment: clipSubviews may be checked on the CustomCell! Try to disable that either is cellForRowAtIndexPath() or in the Interface Builder if using prototype cells!

Comment: Attache images plz

Comment: @simerkaur You should not post codes and images in the comment section. Post it in the Questions for more detail please!

Comment: in method of gesture 
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[gesture view];
    }
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
     cell = (UITableViewCell *)[gesture view];
        cell.updated_imgView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, tableview.frame.size.width, tableview.frame.size.height);
           }
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
     cell = (UITableViewCell *)[gesture view];
        cell.updated_imgView.frame=CGRectMake(30, 0, 300 , 300);
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *reconizer=[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
                   [reconizer setMinimumPressDuration:1.0];
                 [cell addGestureRecognizer:reconizer];


-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)reconizer
{
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[gesture view];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableview indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"row=%1ld",(long)indexPath.row];
    [self setTitle: s];
}
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
 cell = (UITableViewCell *)[gesture view];
    cell.updated_imgView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, tableview.frame.size.width, tableview.frame.size.height);
       }
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
 cell = (UITableViewCell *)[gesture view];
    cell.updated_imgView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

}

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: could you please send the crash message?@simerkaur

Comment: @simerkaur you try to change the image view frame in UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded.

Comment: @simerkaur I Have tried your problem my side and found that when you long press on a image.. it size change according the view size but it show only cell content view.. so my advise is you show the image on a image which size equal to the view size.

Comment: image is show on table view cell but there is a problem of size

Comment: @simerkaur what's problem?

Comment: i want to set the size of image according to main view means screen size but takes the size of cell ...

Comment: @simerkaur I already said you take a image view on the table view and before long pressing you set is hidden .. after long press when you take the response then you set the image on Image View and set the property hidden NO.

Comment: @simerkaur Got my answer?

Comment: @simerkaur You should hidden the image view rather than remove.

Comment: i have also used hidden and remove property , but there is no effect ,sir

Comment: Can you please send the screen shot of your issue?

Answer (score -1):

```
[cell addGestureRecognizer:gesture1]
```

replace with below line

```
[ cell.yourimageview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];  // This enable user interaction on the image view. Required!!


[cell.yourimageview addGestureRecognizer:gesture1];  //yourimageview is your image outlet
```

Comment: is clipViews enabled on the custom cell?

Answer (score -1):

Try it:
Cell is superView of imageView so on size changing it will not cross cell frame
add it to mainView after resize.

Comment: Please provide exception message

Comment: This occur when a class does not respond to a method. before calling check                                                                  if([ActivityFeedViewController instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(celllongpressed:)]){
        /
    }